# open external browser window from swt browser

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jakarta-ee, swt

I'm using swt browser in my Java EE application. On many points of the application, when you click on a link, i do javascript window.open and it is fine, it opens a new window, which is also a headless swt browser child, but at one particular point of the application, when the user clicks on a link, i want it to open on an external default browser like ie/firefox anyone, not the headless swt one.
Is this possible?, also can i do this from my html and javascript/jquery code, if i need to write java code for this, then how do i do that, should i redirect to a jsp and write there, and then how do i call a jsp without doing window.open.

My code is something like this:

```
openWindow = function() {
    window.open("/ShowRequiredPage?customerId=" + com.org.myProject.customerID + "&userId=" + com.org.myProject.userName + "&email=" + com.org.myProject.userName);
}

ActiveContactsRenderer.prototype.renderBody = function(){
    ...

    bodyEl.append('<div id="buyMessage" class="buyMessage">'+
                  '<h2><span>Limited Users</span></h2>'+
                  '<a id="buyButton" href="#"; onclick="openWindow();">Buy This</a></div>');
    ...
}
```

Please any help on this is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is handled by browser settings. There doesn't seem any way to achieve this using `JavaScript/JQuery`. At the max, you can study the params passed to window.open() method and may it help you to understand this more clearly.